# unable to create text area using javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to design a simple text area using javascript. I am using the following function

```
    function add2(type) {
     var element = document.createElement("input");
     var label=prompt("Enter the name for lable","label");
     document.getElementById('raj').innerHTML=document.getElementById('raj').innerHTML+label;
     element.setAttribute("type", type);

     element.setAttribute("name", type);
     element.setAttribute("cols",20);
     element.setAttribute("rows",50);

     var rohit = document.getElementById("raj");
    rohit.appendChild(element);
    document.getElementById('raj').innerHTML=document.getElementById('raj').innerHTML+"<br/>";

}
```

I am using this function in my HTML code as follow :

```
<input type="button" value="Text Area" onclick="add2('textarea')">
```

But when I am executing this code, it is creating only a simple text box. what should I do ??

Thanks

Comment: `createElement("input")` crearted an **input**. How do you expect it to be a textarea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Textarea's have their own HTML tag, I think that this is what you want:

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/SO_AMK/ZzdWR/

HTML:

```
<input type="button" value="Text Area" onclick="add2('textarea')">
<div id="raj">Lorem ipsum...</div>
```

​JavaScript:

```
function add2(name) {
     var element = document.createElement("textarea");
     var label = prompt("Enter the name for lable","label");
     var rohit = document.getElementById("raj");
     rohit.innerHTML = rohit.innerHTML + label;

     element.setAttribute("name", name);
     element.setAttribute("cols",20);
     element.setAttribute("rows",50);

    rohit.appendChild(element);
    rohit.innerHTML = rohit.innerHTML + "<br/>";

}​
```

Answer (score 1):

Text areas are separate elements:

```
<textarea>content</textarea>
```

rather than

```
<input type="textarea" value="content" />
```

Comment: thanks to all . I have put only createElement("textarea") at place of createElement("input");